# Ado.Net - How to use connection pooling?

Tags: .net, ado.net, connection-pooling

.Net allows connection pooling which based on what I've read is simply by adding parameters to App.config

The question is, am I suppose to do anything in my code to use the connection pool?
In my code I open a connection every time data is needed and I close it as soon as I'm done. Am i suppose to do anything special to reuse connections?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special as long as your connections use the same connection string. Use the connection, close it and will automatically return to the pool.

From [SQL Server connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx):

> Connections are pooled per process, per application domain, per
>   connection string and when integrated security is used, per Windows
>   identity. Connection strings must also be an exact match; keywords
>   supplied in a different order for the same connection will be pooled
>   separately.

You can configure certain pool related options in the [connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) itself:

- Pooling (enabled by default)
- Connection Lifetime (or Load Balance Timeout)
- Enlist
- Max Pool Size
- Min Pool Size

Comment: Yep.  The default is to use them.

Answer (score 3):

The point is to not do anything to re-use connections :)  If you store the connection and re-use it, the pool is defeated.

A good pattern is to take advantage of IDisposable and using.  For the ado.net connection classes, dispose calls close.  If you do that, you can't go wrong.

```
using (conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    // use the connection
}
```